# Connecting iPad to a USB powered monitor?

Tags: ipad, macbook-pro, display, ios, jailbreak

I'm thinking about buying a USB powered monitor to connect to my MacBook.

I found so many nice ones and the most suitable was Asus.

ASUS MB MB168B+ 15.6-Inch Screen LED-Lit Monitor

Now that got me wondering if I can also connect my iPad somehow to watch a movie or display something for a client that would be very useful.

I tried looking up anything remotely related to the subject but failed and thats why I'm here asking the experts.

<sup>Jailbroken iPad mini 2 and MacBook Air 11″</sup>

Comment: what is the Asus model?

Comment: ASUS MB MB168B+ 15.6-Inch Screen LED-Lit Monitor

Comment: Did you look where would you connect it on your iPad, or what is the MBA purpose in this?

Comment: it doesn't connect straight away thats my question..

Answer (score 1):

The iPad does not support video output over USB; it's a limitation you cannot work around with a jailbreak. Your only options are [composite](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD826ZM/A/lightning-digital-av-adapter) and [VGA](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD825ZM/A/lightning-to-vga-adapter)  video output via supported Lightening adaptors. There are jailbreaks that allow you to output the video 100% of the time though, not just from apps that support mirroring.

Comment: I don't understand why my comments here keep getting deleted!!??

Comment: Because they add nothing to the answer. This is *not* a chat forum. Commenting that "you'd like another answer" on an existing answer is not constructive. If you want to chat back and forth on something please use [the site chat channel](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat). For more information on how Ask Different and the StackExchange Q&A format works please see our [FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: I believe one of my comments had a solution thats why I asked why it was deleted. But I agree with you & thank you for the clarifications.

Comment: If it's a solution, don't post it as as a comment. Post it as a solution and accept it (assuming it solves your problem).